# interpolate between dates given known index range

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to populate some hard coded "data." The x axis is time in years, and the y axis is a numerical value. The graph will resemble an exponential function. Here is what I have so far, you'll notice the index range (denoted as n) is 100:

```
var data = [];
var n = 100;
var a = 1;
var b = 2;

for(var k = 0; k <100; k++) {
    data.push({x: ???, y: a * Math.pow(b, 0.01 * k)});
}
```

I couldn't quite figure out how to interpolate between dates. My first try was starting with my initial year and adding increments then casting into `String()` for a year, but I wound up with something that was no longer a date. Math operations didn't know I wanted a date output, so I suppose that's my fault. And I have yet to think of a better way.

**Question:**

How do I interpolate between two dates in javascript within a for loop?

- Start date: 1800-01-01
- End date: 2020-01-01
- n: 100

Comment: Do you need pure JS for this?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Well uh, you know what they say, a little bit of d3 couldn't hurt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get **real** date objects, not just strings disguised as dates, by using a time scale and the `invert` method.

For that to work, we just need to set the variables...

```
var n = 100;
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
var startDate = "1800-01-01";
var endDate = "2020-01-01";
```

... and the parser:

```
var parser = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");
```

Now we set the scale. The important part is setting it's range from `0` to `100`. It's the range that we'll use with `invert`, to get the correspondent date:

```
var scale = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain([parser(startDate), parser(endDate)])
  .range([0, n]);
```

Finally we create the array. We can use `d3.range` and get rid of the for loop:

```
var data = d3.range(n).map(function(k) {
  return {
    x: scale.invert(k),
    y: a * Math.pow(b, 0.01 * k)
  }
});
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var n = 100;
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
var startDate = "1800-01-01";
var endDate = "2020-01-01";

var parser = d3.utcParse("%Y-%m-%d");

var scale = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain([parser(startDate), parser(endDate)])
  .range([0, n]);

var data = d3.range(n).map(function(k) {
  return {
    x: scale.invert(k),
    y: a * Math.pow(b, 0.01 * k)
  }
})

console.log(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

As its only the year that increments, it doesn't matter that it's a date - just format the string before pushing into the array

```js
let startYear = 1800;
const endYear = 2020;
const years = [];

for(startYear; startYear <= endYear; startYear++) {
 years.push(`${startYear}-01-01`)    
}

console.log(years)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use can use intervals with dedicated js date/time libraries:

https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/interval.js~Interval.html

https://momentjs.com/

https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs

or
https://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/javascript/calculating-the-difference-between-two-dates-in-javascript.html